# wamp server working with emulator but not with any other android phone

Tags: php, android, mysql, wampserver

I am newbie in android application and want to connect my android application with WAMP Server.For this i took reference of [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/). Things working great till i am using android emulator for debugging and running the application. But when i run same code from actual android device. I unable to connect WAMP server from android device.

Can you please tell me , how to access WAMP server from android device.

Please note :- My android device is not connected with PC or it is not in local area network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you need to modify the bound address for the Apache server. Navigate to this directory: 
*wampinstallation*\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\conf, then open httpd.conf in any text editor.

Ctrl+F to find the line where it says "Listen 127.0.0.1:80" (I'm pretty sure that's the default value), change that to "Listen 80".  This will bind the Apache server to any network interface on port 80, making it accessible within your LAN.

After you've done that, you'll need to restart the Apache service via the Wamp tray icon.

Comment: First of all you are not getting my point i able to run my application on Emulator(Android virtual device) but cannot run the same application in actual android device.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.Tried and restart WAMP server once. But same error found.

Comment: What address are you requesting from in the android application?

Comment: I am not sure my mobile is in same LAN or not.Its like my friend accessing my WAMP server using android device from his home.

Comment: I am using "172.25.64.188". Which my ip address. Connection URL is like,http://172.25.64.188/android_connect/get_all_products.php

Comment: If your device is not on the same LAN, you won't be able to access the WAMP server unless you have it port forwarded and then access it from your device remotely via your public-facing IP address.  You can follow [this](http://simonewebdesign.it/blog/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver/) tutorial to do so.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, But can you please tell us why our localhost:8080 not opening. When i enter http://localhost:8080/ in browser URL i am getting problem in loading page with unable to connect

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45058/discussion-between-k-s-and-aryabhata)